# Joomla moved, now index.php redirects me to root folder

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

A friend of mine asked me for a favour, to move his website. The programmer who made it, send me an archive with the database, and the rest of the files needed. I've installed it on my localhost, with apache, php and mysql installed on it.

I have a problem with it. If I go to localhost/mgro/index2.php, it shows somehow a minimal version of the website, but if I click on something, it gets to index.php?something_else_here and it works. If I go to localhost/mgro I just see the files, and if I go to localhost/mgro/index.php it redirects me to localhost/mgro.

About the configuration file, I've used the configuration.php-dist file, with new info in it. What I've changed was just the database, user and password for the database.

Basically, everything works fine, except that index.php with no requests, because it "backs" me into the folder

**NEW PROBLEM:** If I click on an Add to cart button, it redirects me to the website that is online.

Comment: Having just the site's content files/database aren't enough. You need all of the server configuration stuff. e.g. .htaccess and httpd.conf-level configuration

Answer (score 0):

Is this Joomla 1.5 or Joomla 2.5.x / 3.0? I'm going to guess that you have a potential issue with the `live_site` variable in the configuration.php file, especially if you're using Joomla 1.5. Make sure that it is configured to your localhost's live site URL directory.

Some other things to check:
1) If you're using SEF urls you need to use a .htaccess file. Usually the one Joomla' includes by default works (if you don't have it you can redownload it from Joomla's code repos: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=index

2) When logged in go to global configuration and check the option "URL rewriting". You can try switching it off. (On does require the .htaccess file mentioned before).

3) If you're just seeing files when you hit the directory then Apache isn't configured to load .php files. Since you're running a localhost you'll have to track that down somehow.

Some other notes:
-Index2.php isn't anything, don't use it.